# Adding Latex folders to SVN repository

Tags: svn, latex

I have a folder full of papers written in Latex (each in a separate folder). I'd like to add them all to my SVN repository. How to do that (using Terminal in Mac) but without uploading bin files? I know I should somehow put some files (e.g, *.gz) on ignore list. But how to do that before doing `svn add` (or at the same time)? Also, at the later point, I would like not to see any bin files when I do `svn status`.

Btw, which files (i.e., file endings) should be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property svn:ignore can be set on a directory to ignore files based on the filename.

You can edit it interactively with

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

and a pattern like

```
*.pdf
```

will ignore all PDF files. The list of endings that are to be ignored is pretty long and depends on your modules, it's best to add suffixes as you see them in `svn status`.

Comment: Can it be added recursively or do I need to do it manually for every folder?

Comment: Every folder. If you want to clone the svn:ignore property, have a look at svn propset and svn propget.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `svn add` first and then `svn ignore` on those files/folders you don't want.
Nothing is added to the remote repository until you execute `svn commit`.